# problems in git upgrade

Tags: upgrade, package-management, git

when I run upgrade in my ubuntu 10.04,the result is

```
~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  git git-all git-arch git-cvs git-daemon-run git-email git-gui git-man git-svn gitk gitweb linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic ubufox
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
```

why are some packages not upgraded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Those packages should be forced to update.

`dist-upgrade` will install all pending updates, with their new dependencies. If for some reason, you don't want to do that, you should use `apt-get install package-name dependency-package-name` instead.